# How check that migrations is enabled in asp.net mvc project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In work I created asp.net mvc project with enabled migrations. pushed it to gitlab and cloned to home PC. How check that migrations is enabled in asp.net mvc project on home clone of project?

Answer (score 0):

You can check by nuget command

```
Update-Database
```